# XSLT - how to group output by common child element value and with hierarchical data in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file like the below where I may have multiple records with a common child element like so:

```
    <person>
      <name>Alice</name> /* root node
      <account>001</account>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>Alice</name>
      <account>002</account>
    </person>
```

How would I transform this to the below using `XSLT 2.0`?

```
    <person>
      <name>Alice</name>
     <child-detail>
      <account>001</account>
      <account>002</account>
     </child-detail>
    </person>
```

'I'm fairly new to XSLT so please excuse the potentially novice question. Any guidance would be appreciated here. Thanks in advance.'

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. Also do a search - grouping is probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Come back if you run into a **specific**  difficulty in your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it simply using *for-each-group*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//person" group-by="name">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
        <child-detail>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/account"/>
        </child-detail>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```